# ViewModel.Attach causing ArgumentException in XAML due to being already registered

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependencies

I have the following methods to register a progress bar UserControl with the ViewModel's events:

```
private void SetProgressBar(ProgressBar progressBar)
        {
            _progressBar = progressBar;
            _progressBar.SizeChanged += (s, e) => ComputeViewModelProperties();
            RegisterForNotification("Value", progressBar, (d, e) => ComputeViewModelProperties());
            RegisterForNotification("Maximum", progressBar, (d, e) => ComputeViewModelProperties());
            RegisterForNotification("Minimum", progressBar, (d, e) => ComputeViewModelProperties());

            ComputeViewModelProperties();
        }

private void RegisterForNotification(string propertyName, FrameworkElement element, PropertyChangedCallback callback)
        {

            //Bind to a dependency property  
            Binding b = new Binding(propertyName) { Source = element };



            Prop = System.Windows.DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "ListenAttached" + propertyName,
                typeof(object),
                typeof(UserControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(callback));

            element.SetBinding(Prop, b);
        }
```

When I first added the ProgressBar control to the XAML, I received no errors. However, when editing the XAML to add other controls, I cut and pasted the ProgressBar to move it, and received the error:

```
ArgumentException: 'ListenAttachedValue' property was already registered by 'UserControl'.
```

Why did removing and adding back this control cause the error? Why didn't it cause an issue at the first implementation? Should there not also be corresponding errors for the registration of "Maximum" and "Minimum?"

My XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding Value}"  
                 Width="80" Height="80" 
                 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                 Style="{StaticResource SegmentedProgressBarStyle}" />
```

**EDIT:** More code from source

```
public static CircularProgressBarViewModel GetAttach(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (CircularProgressBarViewModel)d.GetValue(AttachProperty);
        }

        public static void SetAttach(DependencyObject d, CircularProgressBarViewModel value)
        {
            d.SetValue(AttachProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Change handler for the Attach property
        /// </summary>
        private static void OnAttachChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // set the view model as the DataContext for the rest of the template
            FrameworkElement targetElement = d as FrameworkElement;
            CircularProgressBarViewModel viewModel = e.NewValue as CircularProgressBarViewModel;
            targetElement.DataContext = viewModel;

            // handle the loaded event
            targetElement.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Element_Loaded);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle the Loaded event of the element to which this view model is attached
        /// in order to enable the attached
        /// view model to bind to properties of the parent element
        /// </summary>
        static void Element_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement targetElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
            CircularProgressBarViewModel attachedModel = GetAttach(targetElement);

            // find the ProgressBar and associated it with the view model
            var progressBar = targetElement.Ancestors<ProgressBar>().Single() as ProgressBar;
            attachedModel.SetProgressBar(progressBar);
        }
```

Full source: [circular progress bar](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/02/07/a-circular-progressbar-style-using-an-attached-viewmodel.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this particular problem like this:

```
public static DependencyProperty AttachedProperty;
```

And since the property is registered once, I just reuse it to bind to the callback.

```
private void RegisterForNotification(string propertyName, FrameworkElement element, PropertyChangedCallback callback)
{

  //Bind to a dependency property  
  Binding b = new Binding(propertyName) { Source = element };
        if (AttachedProperty == null)
        {
          AttachedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "ListenAttached" + propertyName,
          typeof(object),
          typeof(MainWindow),
          new PropertyMetadata(callback));
        }

  element.SetBinding(AttachedProperty, b);
}
```

Unfortunately this Silverlight project has a bit more work before you can use it in your WPF application, which I guess is our commong goal.